# Arial font is doing something weird with the letter spacing in uppercase only

Tags: html, css, sass

The spacing between the "A", "C" and "T" is wider than the spacing between the other letters.
What is causing this and how do I solve it?

[image: activiteiten]

```html
<main class="container">
  <div class="body wide">
    <header role="banner" class="banner">
      <h1 class="js-quickedit-page-title">
        <span property="schema:name">Activiteiten</span>
        </h1>
    </header>
```

Here's my element inspection:

[image: inspection]
[image: inspection2]

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v9qwo93g/1/

Not sure if I have to post any more code html/css, I will if requested!

Comment: Please share your HTML code.

Comment: That's actually pretty hard, but give me a minute!

Comment: Tried reloading the page with JavaScript disabled, same issue.

Comment: What If you trying to add ```letter-spacing```?

Comment: But not G? What about U?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the font itself that seems to have this inconsistent letter-spacing. Check it out in a text editor, it does not even have to be bold:

[image: uneven letter spacing in unbolded Arial]

[image]

*On the images you see Arial (not bold), edited in Paint. The red lines both have the same thickness.*

In your example its getting even worse because of the small font-size and rounding issues. I don't see a way of getting this solved, except using another font.
If you are interested in this this topic, you probably have a better chance of getting deeper insights when asking some experts on [graphicdesign.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) or similar pages.

Comment: This is actually the reverse of my situation. Here you have more spacing between "TI" than between "CT". In my case there's more spacing betwee "CT"

Comment: Also here it seems to work properly: https://gyazo.com/53df2ef7a87d50cb0b5e3b4220f63628 - https://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/arial

Comment: It shows the reverse of your situation, because it is not bold. The issue is the same. Also on your linked website it shows this behaviour but you have to [zoom in](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/161223/oucuvonu.png) to be able to see it. Also keep in mind that nearly every browser renders text differently and pixel rounding comes into play when the font-size gets too small.

Comment: Works perfectly on my smarthphone though :)
Boss is saying it has something to do with the way the browser renders the text.

Comment: Damn these fonts with inconsistent letter-spacing! I guess I know what this "web font" thing means now...

Answer (score 0):

Try font-weight: bold instead of 700?

Comment: Changing font-weight to normal solves it (except that the text is no longer bold, which I do want), but changing it back to bold or 700 has the same weird spacing.

Comment: Very odd, have you tried to use a reset.css tool just to test what happends?

Comment: Very strange, do you have a codepen or online version of this?

Comment: Is this just normal for Arial in uppercase?

Comment: Your jsfiddle looks correct in my browser, does it also for you?

Comment: It's a bit better, but still has more spacing behind the C than the T

Comment: not sure if this will help but remove the " quotes around Arial.

Answer (score -1):

## `font-kerning: normal;`

There is a formal name to the process of fixing the issue mentioned by the OP, called **kerning**.

This information of how much space between `A` and `V` would be more pleasant to read can be embedded in the font.

For such cases `CSS` has the [font-kerning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning) property to make use of this information.

Those interested please read [Kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning).